# Show $ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin (ax)}{x}dx $ is an entire function.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, entire-functions

I am struggling in evaluating the following integral:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin (ax)}{x}dx$$

I know that if the integral is from $0$ to infinity, it will be a constant of $\pi/2$ which is analytic, but not sure when it's from 0 to 1.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Sine_integral

Comment: Actually, $$f(a):=\int_0^\infty\,\frac{\sin(ax)}{x}\,\text{d}x$$ is not analytic.  At least, $f$ is not analytic on the whole $\mathbb{R}$.  (It is analytic on $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ only.)  The integral diverges if $a$ is not real, so $f$ is not analytic outside $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that\begin{align}\int_0^1\frac{\sin(ax)}x\,\mathrm dx&=\int_0^1\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^na^{2n+1}x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}\,\mathrm dx\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\int_0^1\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}\,\mathrm dx\right)a^{2n+1}\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)\times(2n+1)!}a^{2n+1}.\end{align}

Comment: Can't we write it in closed form?

Comment: I would say that $\int_0^1\frac{\sin(ax)}x\,\mathrm dx$ **is** in closed form.

Comment: Your question got me confused. Isn't writing a function $f\colon\mathbb{C}\longrightarrow\mathbb C$ as $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ a natural way of showing that it is an entire function?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos  Technically, we also need to prove that the radius of convergence is infinite.  But the OP should be able to complete the job.

Comment: @Batominovski That's so easy that I didn't think about mentioning it.

Answer (score 1):

You may simply notice that
$$ F(a)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin(ax)}{x}\,dx \stackrel{x\mapsto\frac{z}{a}}{=}\int_{0}^{a}\frac{\sin z}{z}\,dz $$
so $F'(a)=\frac{\sin a}{a}$ is an entire function. This implies that $F(z)$ is an entire function too (the space of entire functions is closed with respect to $\frac{d}{dz}$ and $\int(\ldots)\,dz$, since these operators do not alter the radius of convergence of a power series).